# Coding anomaly in java script, cant seem to find the issue

Tags: javascript

Basically my code below works but there is a problem to it which I recently discovered. As I was running it the pictures seem to come in the wrong order. I ran it with google chrome and using inspect element I found the order it went in was image1>image4>image1>image2>image4>image1 and so on in order but the starting order is not right and I cant seem to find the source of the issue and running it with google chromes html console cant seem to find the problem.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="image1.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Next Light</button>

<script>

var lights = new Array("image2.jpg","image4.jpg","image1.jpg");



var index = 0;
var lightsLen = lights.length;

function nextLightClick() {
    index++;

    if (index == lightsLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = lights[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you edit your question to this? What does this have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an anomaly, you're increasing your index counter *before* you run the rest of your function so the first image is at the `[1]` index instead of `[0]`.

Move it to the end of the function and it works as you'd expect.

```
function nextLightClick() {
    if (index == lightsLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = lights[index];

    index++;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vju0sy4w/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well arrays start at index 0, and you're incrementing your counter immediately, so the index will start at 1 (the 2nd item). Try this instead:

```
(function() {
  var srcIndex = -1, // Start at -1 since you're incrementing right off the bat (first index will be zero)
      lightsLen = lights.length,
      image = document.getElementById('starting_light');

  // If this needs to be global
  window.nextLightClick = function() {
    srcIndex++;

    if (srcIndex === lightsLen) { 
      srcIndex = 0;
    }

    image.src = lights[srcIndex];
  };
})();
```

Comment: Incrementing afterwards would eliminate the dependency on an unnecessarily broader variable.

Comment: A "broader" variable? It's the same thing except for how it's initialized. You still need the `index` variable, which I just renamed `srcIndex`. There's literally no difference except personal preference.

Comment: Your variable was declared outside of the function that truly cares about it.  Scoping matters, even if it's personal preference.

Comment: Are you talking about the `image` variable? Yes, I declared it within a private scope outside of that function because other functions may want to use it, _and_ it's bad practice to perform the same DOM lookup multiple times. Cache it!

Comment: No, I'm talking about `srcIndex`.  It has no earthly business outside of that anonymous function.

Comment: `srcIndex` is not outside of the private scope, it's within. Are you seeing your code? You instead made `index` a _global_, which is a terrible, terrible, **terrible** idea.

Comment: I just realized it was Jason's code, not yours, but my point stands - my `srcIndex` variable is _privately_ scoped, while the other answer leaves it as a global.

Comment: Are you serious? It wasn't an "idea" to leave it as a global, I assume at SO that people follow the directions and that OP made a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) considering the entire thing is boiled down and every variable is global. The point would then be to take these examples and implement them into whatever namespace you're using.